# What modelling approach can I use for my problem?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a longitudinal dataset where I want to predict future sales of products, however, the dimension of the timeframe across products are not constant, for example product 1 has data for months between January and August and product 2 has data for months between September and December. Each product exist in a category and each category has a specific time series trend across the year. I somehow want to use this information, collectively with the individual covariaties which describe the products to make predictions.

What approach can I use for this?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115431/what-modelling-approach-can-i-use)